# imagecreatefromjpeg - If image not found use default

Tags: php

I'm trying merge a large group of images onto a new background but I am using the file names from a database, when the script cannot find the top image I would like to be able to use a default one:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($part);
if (!$src) { 
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('default.jpg'); 
}
```

Just to make things clear:

If $part is not found use default.jpg

I had a search around and found the above but I cannot seem to get it to work it just outputs the background on its own (like before), am I missing something here as I thought this should look for $part and if not found it should use default.jpg

Many Thanks,
David

Comment: are you getting any errors on default.jpg as well?

Comment: Nope no errors on the default, it shows:

failed to open stream: No such file or directory - in reference to $part

Thanks,

Comment: use `@imagecreatefromjpeg($part)` - the @ symbol will suppress the error message. take a look at [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) on [php.net](http://php.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function

Comment: Hi,
Thanks I will have a look at this now and report back

Comment: Better to use is_readable(), which confirms that the file exists AND can be read.

Answer (score 0):

The imagecreatefromjpeg should return false if there are any errors. Could you first check if $part is a valid file? Before you attempt to make an image of it.